# IN condition is not working in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to delete some collections from MongoDB based on some conditions.

I am using `{ $in: deleteModule}`, where `deletemodule` is an array `["ab","bc"]`.

But its deleting only the record which is existing first in the collection.

```
myDb.collection('ABC').findAndModify(
        {'projectName': projectName, 'companyName': companyName,'moduleName':{ $in: deleteModule}},
        [['_id', 'asc']],
        { 'remove': true },
```

Comment: As documentation says about that query criteria `Although the query may match multiple documents, findAndModify will only select one document to modify`

Comment: why don't you use `remove` ?

Comment: Thnx guys, later i saw that findAndModify will select only one record, then i use remove...thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$in` condition to achieve the result

```
ABC.remove({ moduleName: { $in: deleteModule } })
```

Answer (score 1):

`findAndModify` can be used to atomically modify a document (at most one) and return it. It will remove only the first matched document. This is how it is implemented. 
The official document says so: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/

Use remove for your use case.
Example:

```
db.users.remove({'_id':{'$in':inactive_users}})
```